# Multiple Elastic IP for EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli

For a single EC2 instance, I have added 2IP Address Primary and one secondary. Later i cant remove one..

Is there any way that we can remove one IP Adresss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can remove the seconday IP address..

- In the EC2 Console, Open the navigation pane, Choose the  instance
- Under Actions --> Networking --> Manage IP Address
- Under IPv4, Choose unassign for the IP address to unassign
- Finally update the changes.